# Iterating over "triangular" portion of a 4D matrix

Tags: matrices

If I have a symmetrical matrix of size `n x n`, say:

```
A = [ 0 3 5 0 4
      3 0 1 2 0
      5 1 0 0 6
      0 2 0 0 2
      4 0 6 2 0 ]
```

(representing the weights of edges between vertex `i` and vertex `j` in an adjacency matrix, but that is beside the point)

The easiest way to iterate over this matrix is to use a nested loop:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        value = A[i][j]
```

However, this means that i am "doubling up" on the symmetrical parts of the matrix ie. `(i,j) = (j,i)`. To avoid this I can change the nested loop to:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        value = A[i][j]
```

Which only iterates over the top triangular part of the matrix (ignoring `i = j` because it is always 0)

My question is: What is the 4 dimensional equivalent of this?

If I want to compare every element in `A` with every other element in `A`, this is the equivalent of placing a copy of matrix `A` perpendicular to the edge of the original `A` matrix and iterating over the "cube" generated.

I can do this with:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        value1 = A[i][j]
        for k in range(n):
            for l in range(k+1, n):
                value2 = A[k][l]
                foo(value1, value2)
```

My problem is that this does not take into account that:

`foo(A[3][5], A[2][4])` is exactly the same as `foo(A[2][4], A[3][5])`

Is there a way that I can structure my loops such that the symmetries of the 4 dimensional matrix can be exploited in the way that those of the 2 dimensional one were in my second example?

Please ignore the fact that I am using 'pythonic' pseudocode for my examples, I am not after a python specific answer - more just an understanding of how the loop structure would work; so I can implement it in any language..

Comment: So what you want to do is to iterate through all elements above the the main diagonal two-by-two without repeating any set of pairs?

Comment: Pretty much. I am having trouble visualising it in 3 (or maybe 4?) dimensions. But yes. Iterate over all pairs from two identical, symmetrical 2D matrices, without repeating any pairs..

Comment: Do you want to include or exclude `foo(A[2][4], A[2][4])`?

Comment: exclude, i suppose, as they will be the same value and the function operating on them will be a comparative function

Answer (score 1):

With your initial code, you check each 'checkmark':

\begin{array} {c|ccccc}
i/j&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
1&.&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
2&.&.&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
3&.&.&.&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
4&.&.&.&.&\checkmark\\
5&.&.&.&.&.&\\
\end{array}

With the second array, you will need to check each $(i,j)_{A_1}$ against each $(i,j)_{A_2}$, but only if $i_1\le i_2$ AND $j_1\le j_2$, excepting if both $i_1=i_2$ and $j_1=j_2$.

This motivation is because although we have defined equality in matrix $A_1$ and $A_2$, we have not defined equality between an element of $A_1$ and an element of $A_2$, which can be defined as $(i_1=i_2) \land 
(j_1=j_2)$.

So for example, if from matrix $A_1$ we are considering $(1,2)$, we check:

\begin{array} {c|ccccc}
i/j&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
1&.&\color{red}\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
2&.&.&\checkmark&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
3&.&.&.&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
4&.&.&.&.&\checkmark\\
5&.&.&.&.&.&\\
\end{array}

and if we are considering $(2,4)$, we check:

\begin{array} {c|ccccc}
i/j&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
1&.&.&.&.&.\\
2&.&.&.&\color{red}\checkmark&\checkmark\\
3&.&.&.&\checkmark&\checkmark\\
4&.&.&.&.&\checkmark\\
5&.&.&.&.&.&\\
\end{array}

So your code should look more like:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1, n): [
        for k in range(i,n):
            for l in range(j, n): [
                if [i!=k && j!=l]: [
                    value1 = A[i][j]
                    value2 = A[k][l]
                    foo(value1, value2)
                                   ]
                                  ]
                           ]
```